# Need to connect php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Search']))
      {
        //Database connection
        $num = $_POST['num'];
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = '';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error
        connecting to mysql');
        $dbname = 'vasuki';
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $Result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, age FROM details WHERE id =
        '$num'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
           {
                $name = $row['name'] ;
                $age = $row['age'];
                //Creating table 
                   echo "<div style='top: 273px;
                   margin-left: 60px;
                   position: absolute;left: 30px;'>
                   <table border='1'><tr><th>name</th>
                   <th> age </th></tr>
                   //Connect to Database to fetch the data
                   <td>echo'<?php $name ?>;'</td>
                   <td>echo'<?php $age ?>;'</td>
                   </table></div>";
        }
```

I have a data in my xampp database.

In front end using php I need to search the data and find the data from database.

I just pasted only php code here.I hope I did some mistake in above the code.

I have a doubt on this below code :

```
 <td>echo'<?php $name ?>;'</td>
```

Is this a corrct syntax?.

Because I am getting error in above the line.

I am using it inside echo cmd so I have a doubt. Kindly clarify

Comment: *"Because I am getting error in above the line."* - Being what exactly? - *"Kindly clarify"* - Err... you're the one who needs to clarify. Plus, we've no way to know if those POST arrays are ok or not.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and the mysql_*() functions are obsolete, deprecated, and REMOVED from newer php versions. And exactly **HOW** is this code not working?

Comment: Oh, my head hurts. As with the afore mentioned mysql_* deprecation, you can't use an echo within an echo statement, can't use php tags within a php block...

Comment: _"I have a data in my xampp database."_ xampp is not a database. Xampp is a PHP development environment which uses MariaDB as a database.

Comment: Thank you so much to all. I changed the echo function. :-) Now It is working Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Search']))
      {
        //Database connection
        $num = $_POST['num'];
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = '';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error
        connecting to mysql');
        $dbname = 'vasuki';
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $Result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, age FROM details WHERE id =
        '$num'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
           {
                $name = $row['name'] ;
                $age = $row['age'];
                //Creating table 
                   echo "<div style='top: 273px;
                                   margin-left: 60px;
                                   position: absolute;left: 30px;'>
                                       <table border='1'><tr><th>name</th>
                                       <th> age </th></tr><tr>
                                       <td> $name </td>
                                       <td> $age </td></tr>
                                       </table></div>";
        }
?>
```

You already started echo keyword and all html code are inside of (") and (") then you can not write echo inside echo and PHP automatically understand $identifier as a variable.

**Another way for same result is:**

```
echo "<div style='top: 273px;
margin-left: 60px;
position: absolute;left: 30px;'>
<table border='1'><tr><th>name</th>
<th> age </th></tr><tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$age."</td></tr></table></div>";
```

Here dot (.) is used for concatenate.

**Or you can do this as well:**

```
echo "<div style='top: 273px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        position: absolute;left: 30px;'>
        <table border='1'><tr><th>name</th>
        <th> age </th></tr><tr><td>";
echo $name;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $age;
echo "</td></tr></table></div>";
```

Do what you feel easy.

Comment: Thank you so much Madhu, It is working now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your doubts are correct, this line is completely wrong:

```
echo "<div style='top: 273px;
      [..snip..]
   <td>echo'<?php $name ?>;'</td>
```

PHP is not recursively executable. That `<?php` is **NOT** a php code tag, because it's already inside a PHP string started back on that `echo` line.

Even if it WASN'T inside this string, and was proper PHP code, it'd do nothing.

```
 <?php $foo; ?>
```

just says "here's a var", and php goes. "Gee, thanks", and moves on. You need to echo that var:

```
<?php echo $foo; ?>
```

to get that variable's value as output.

Since you're in a string already, all you need is

```
echo "<div etc...
    <td>$name</td>
    etc...
    ";
```

Note the **LACK** of any php code, other than the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo'<?php $name ?>;'` and `echo'<?php $age ?>;'` to `{$name}` and `{$age}`.

Comment: You really could learn something from Marc's answer  An added explanation is beneficial to all.

Comment: Advice taken. Thank you.